# asp.net repeater for each row

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a repeater that retrieve data from my db.
some of the results are getting a null value in a specific column due to
a join query and its fine.

I would like to go over each row and if the result is null for the specific
row i want to change the css for this row.

Now for the code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repRequests" OnItemDataBound="repRequests_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbltest" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("val_name") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

C#:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("check_accepted", con);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val_name", Session["valName"].ToString());
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        repRequests.DataSource = dr;
        repRequests.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**How to write this ?**

```
protected void repRequests_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        **//what i want to get:**

        if (dr["accepted_id"] == Null) // a column from the db table
        {
            repRequests.attribute["class"] = "Some Class"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the helpers !

Comment: What is `dr` you are referring in `ItemDataBound`?

Comment: is, from the sql query result.

Comment: take a look here, should be suitable for you (after a bit of modification): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @GiladAdar refer to my solution, I have identified that you need to find label control and supply CssClass of that control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following. If the data source is a DataReader object, you must cast e.Item.DataItem as type DBDataRecord (from System.Data.Common)

```
protected void repRequests_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord dataRow = e.Item.DataItem as System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord;
        if (dataRow["accepted_id"] == DBNull.Value || dataRow["accepted_id"] == null) // a column from the db table
        {
          // I am not sure how to you get repRequests. but you can find the control using e.Row.Item.FindControl() function
           repRequests.attribute["class"] = "Some Class";
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Further to your questions, if you want to change the css of a perticular row, if some value is null, you cannot set css to repeater or repeater item directly. What you need to do is add a top level panel to the ItemTemplate like this

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panelRow">
        <asp:Label ID="lbltest" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("val_name") %>'></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Then you can change the css of the panel like below

```
protected void repRequests_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
                    e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                {
                    System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord dataRow = e.Item.DataItem as System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord;

                    if (dataRow["accepted_id"] == DBNull.Value || dataRow["accepted_id"] == null) // a column from the db table
                    {
                        Panel panelRow = e.Item.FindControl("panelRow") as Panel;
                        panelRow.CssClass = "yourcssclass";

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Ok, its working, thanks ! could you help with the repRequests class ? how do i need to write it?

Comment: Of which class do you want to change? Repeater itself will not have any class. To change css of a row, you need add a panel or div to the top level of the ItemTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [**link**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317582) example of `DbDataRecord` when you bind repeater control with sqldatareader.

Also note that `repRequests.attribute["class"] = "Some Class"` this means you are applying CSS Class to the repeater control. You need to change the `CssClass` label which is used as item of repeater control.

```
protected void repRequests_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
         e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
         DbDataRecord dbr = (DbDataRecord)e.Item.DataItem;
         if( Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(dbr, "accepted_id")) == null )
             ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbltest")).CssClass = "Some Class";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing a shorter way for doing it.

Answer (score 1):

If not, you can use IsNull in your query.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select IsNull(something,zero) from sometable",connectionstring)
SqlDatareader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(dr.Read())
{
   if(dr.GetString(0)=="zero")
   {
        repRequests.attribute["class"] = "Some Class";
   }
}
```